# Bootstrap table - sortPriority in multiple-sort extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I use [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and [multiple-sort](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/multiple-sort) extension. In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jupitor/h2c683cn/) is working extension. In my table initial order of first column is wrong (looks like initial ordering is not executed) and I don't know why.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbmhmdxu/1/)

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" id="table3" data-show-columns="true" data-show-multi-sort="true" data-sort-priority='[{"sortName":"CustomerName","sortOrder":"desc"}]'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-field="CustomerName" data-sortable="true">CustomerN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectName" data-sortable="true">ProjectN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectType" data-sortable="true">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectDetails" data-sortable="true">ProjectD</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#table3').bootstrapTable({
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the initial configuration options so that sorting is done when the table is initialised in jQuery itself like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#table3').bootstrapTable(
  {"sortName": "CustomerName","sortOrder":"desc"});
});
```

If you do not pass any sorting options when you are initialising the table it won't do anything except enabling sort.

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbmhmdxu/6/).

Comment: yep, seems like the only option for now... current bootstrap version is buggy: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/70