# Bootstrap-table - sorting isn't correct with data-reactid attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table, columnsorting

in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433235/bootstrap-table-sortpriority-in-multiple-sort-extension-doesnt-work) I asked how to define initial sorting order, but I noticed that sorting is not correct with `data-reactid` attributes. I use [bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) with react.js, which generates `data-reactid` attributes.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64ce96gw/) - table with `data-reactid` attributes, sorting is not correct

If you order *"CustomerN"* column, sequence of rows is not correct.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztc2ng8q/) - table without `data-reactid` attributes, sorting is correct

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" id="table3" data-show-columns="true" data-show-multi-sort="true">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-field="CustomerName" data-sortable="true">CustomerN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectName" data-sortable="true">ProjectN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectType" data-sortable="true">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectDetails" data-sortable="true">ProjectD</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td data-customer-id="49" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$51.1:$0"><a data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$51.1:$0.0">Quiksilver</a></td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Vix eu erant doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum."
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td data-customer-id="80" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$71.1:$0"><a data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$71.1:$0.0">asdasd</a></td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td> 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam"
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td data-customer-id="40" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$66.1:$0"><a data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$66.1:$0.0">dell</a></td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no."
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td data-customer-id="30" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$1.1:$0"><a data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$1.1:$0.0">dell</a></td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no."
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td data-customer-id="10" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$54.1:$0"><a data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$54.1:$0.0">Rip Curl</a></td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no."
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$2.1:$0" data-customer-id="2"><a data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.1.$2.1:$0.0">Java</a></td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no."
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
  $('#table3').bootstrapTable(
  {"sortName": "CustomerName","sortOrder":"asc"});
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use React and jQuery like that together. The entire idea of React is to avoid manual DOM manipulations.

Comment: Take a look at [react-bootstrap-table](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table)

Comment: I know, but I would spend really long time to develop some components which are already developed in jQuery and react-bootstrap-table doesn't fit to my needs, I use a lot of plugins for bootstrap-table.

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be using `React` unless you want to go through a lot of pain with code dropping in and out of `React`

Comment: My application is already developed without any pain, this is the only one thing which doesn't work in my table component.

Comment: Can you show the entire component please then? We might be able to work with it.

Comment: Sorting doesn't work because bootstrap-table sorting functions probably do something with `data-reactid` attributes. I provided jsfiddles and entire component is too huge. I should remove react tag, because I think this issue has nothing to do react...

Comment: Sorting the columns works for me in both fiddles. What exactly is the issue? The fiddles only show the table code - I want to see the React code (if it is a React issue)

Comment: If you want to order "CustomerN" column, sequence of rows is not correct.

Comment: I see it now. Sorry. I'm going to say it's not a React issue. The table shouldn't be affected by attributes it doesn't care about. Maybe a bug with it? Seems very strange though.

Comment: backlink to github issue by same user: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you debug the problem code using developer tools, you will realize that the values used for sorting are not the actual customer names, but the entire `<a href=""...>dell</a>`. Since you are using default sorter, the string comparison considers entire string to be used for comparison. The data-reactid is not clashing with boostraptable library but it has side effects due to the value assigned to this attribute. While doing comparison for sorting, since the beginning of the string is similar, the change in data-reactid is determining the position of element.

There are two approaches to solve this problem.

1. Append data-value attribute to hyperlink and it should appear immediately after `a` tag. E.g. `<a data-value="dell" data-reactid...></a>`
2. Use formatter provided by bootstrap table and keep the data displayed in columns clean.